# Rails STI - custom association in subclass

Tags: activerecord, sti

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end

class Gallery < Upload
    has_many :images
end

class MusicAlbum < Upload
    has_many :audio_tracks
end
```

Should this work as expected? Will Gallery and MusicAlubm models inherit :comments association from their parent (Upload) and add their own?

Comment: One reason to declare all associations in base class will be ability to eager-load all associations when loading uploads. In other words I could do ```Upload.all include: [:comments, :images, :audio_tracks]```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the models are just classes, and when inherited they get all the methods from parent class. So, as both `Gallery` and `MusicAlbum` are descendants from `Upload` model, they will have the `has_many :comments` association, and both will get data from `uploads` db table (which needs to have a `type` column to support STI for this model)

A nice simple STI example can be found [here](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=3815)

Comment: I'm not worrying about inheriting methods, more about things like reflection. I fear issues like Rails expecting all associations are defined on base class and reflects on associations of only this class. 

The example does not customise associations in subclasses. Did you ever try that in a "real" project? Did it work without issues?

Comment: associations are just lists of methods which are generated by Rails and work certain way. So yes, it works for sure, it's no matter where the association is declared - in the model itself or in it's parent. Actually you can even declare it in a module and include that module into your class

Comment: That's interesting about Modules, they only way I recall is to do it in "included" or "extended" callbacks which declares them in context of including classes. Do you know a way to have association methods defined in a module so that it could be included in a module (without callbacks?).

There's more than defined methods, that much I know. Otherwise how would Model.reflections work?

Comment: Regardless of that, I'm accepting your answer. I asked if it's ok and you said "yes". The fact that I'm not convinced but can't verify your claim might indicated a problem with my question :P

Moving association down into subclasses seem to work well in my project.